# How can i change button style dynamically in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm pretty new to React so I'm pretty sure it's something trivial but I'm really struggling to figure it out. I've got a button as a component inside a multi-step form. The button's default type is 'submit' as it is nested within a form element. I have already implemented 'onClick' to navigate through the various steps (5 in total).

I would now like the button type to be 'button' for steps 1-4 and change to 'submit' when in step 5.

Here is the button component:

```js
function Btn(props) {
  return (
    <button
      type={props.type}
      className={Styling[props.class]}
      onClick={props.onClick}
      disabled={props.disabled}
      style={{ visibility: props.visibility, display: props.display }}
    >
      {props.text}
    </button>
  );
}
```

And here is how it's used:

```js
function FindTransportationForm(props) {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(1);

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    pointOfLoading: '',
    pointOfDelivery: '',
    cargoWeightInKg: 0,
    vegetables: 'unchecked',
  });

  const Titles = ['Itinerary', 'Cargo details', 'Capacity requirements', 'Additional information', 'Pick-up'];

  const StepDisplay = () => {
    if (step == 1) {
      return (
        <Itinerary
          pointOfLoading={formData.pointOfLoading}
          pointOfDelivery={formData.pointOfDelivery}
          formData={formData}
          setFormData={setFormData}
        />
      );
    } else if (step == 2) {
      return <CargoInformation />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <form className={Styling['find-transportation-form']}>
      <span className={Styling['steps']}>
        Step {step} out of {Titles.length}
      </span>

      <div className={Styling['title']}>
        <h2>{Titles[step - 1]}</h2>
      </div>
      <div className={Styling['body']}>{StepDisplay()}</div>
      <div className={Styling['footer']}>
        <div className={Styling['buttons-container']}>
          <Btn
            class={step === Titles.length ? 'btn-green' : 'btn-green'}
            text={step === Titles.length ? 'find transportation' : 'next'}
            type={step === Titles.length ? 'submit' : 'button'}
            onClick={() => {
              setStep((currStep) => currStep + 1);
            }}
            display={step < Titles.length ? 'block' : 'block'}
          />
          {/* 
              <Btn
                  class={ step === Titles.length ? "btn-green-submit": "btn-green"}
                  text={step === Titles.length ? "find transportation": "next"}
                  type="submit"
                  display={step === Titles.length ? "block": "none"}
              />
          
              */}

          <Btn
            class="btn-text"
            text="back"
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              setStep((currStep) => currStep - 1);
            }}
            disabled={step == 1}
            visibility={step === 1 ? 'hidden' : 'visible'}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export default FindTransportationForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update button's type as your form steps change :)

```js
            <Btn
                class={ step === Titles.length ? "btn-green": "btn-green"}
                text={step === Titles.length ? "next": "next"}            
                onClick={() => {
                        setStep((currStep) => currStep + 1);

                }}
                display={step < Titles.length ? "block": "block"}
                type={step === 5 ? 'submit' : 'button'} // <------
            />
```

Comment: Thanks Max. I'm trying to implement this but as soon as I get to step 5 it submits.

Comment: What do you mean by "it submits"? So you go from step 4 to step 5 and then what happens?

Comment: When I go from step 4 to step 5 it immediately jumps to a fresh page on step 1.

Comment: Hmm, can share other code related to the form? Perhaps, your step 4 is "array-based"(starts from 0) or something else, and therefore our condition should be `step === 6 ? 'submit' : 'button'`

Comment: Just edited to include the entire form

Comment: This is weird because I don't see any problem in the other code... Well, you could try looking at the rendered HTML and attempt to match it with what you need. Because apparently, 'submit' type is set a step before(that shouldn't happen). Maybe there's another way that triggers form submission, which I'm not aware of

Comment: Thanks Max. For now I'll just substitute the button for another button with type submit at step === 5.